# Change backgroud color of a checkbox

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system, css

I want to change the color of my checkbox in lightning

I have the following piece of code in my cmp

```
 <lightning:input type="checkbox" label="P" 
                                 class="{!(v.isPVisible == true) ? 'selected' : ''}"
                                 onchange="{!c.change}"/>
```

and the following in css

```
.THIS .selected{
    background-color: #EEE;
}
```

the problem here is that, I want to change the color of the checkbox, (where the tick mark comes up), not the checkbox label. By the above code , the label background color gets changed

Comment: have you tried other selectors? the one you are using seems to be invalid in the context fo your component

Comment: I am not sure what other selector I can use. I am not very well versed with css styling. The above code just highlights the checkbox label with the defined colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<lightning:input type="checkbox"` inherits the styling and markup from the checkbox as shown in the [Lightning Design System's Checkbox Blueprint](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/checkbox/).

So you are trying to change the color of the square which is `<span class="slds-checkbox_faux"></span>`

> Edited the answer to add the step to change the color of the tick mark as well

**Changing the background color of the square:**

You need to add just one more selector, `.slds-checkbox_faux` to the CSS class that you have already written.

```
.THIS .selected .slds-checkbox_faux{
background: #EEE;
}
```

And it will change the background color of just the square part of the checkbox.
[image]

**Changing the color of the tick mark:**

You can use the `:after` selector for the `.slds-checkbox_faux` CSS class

```
.THIS .selected .slds-checkbox_faux:after{
border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(75, 202, 129) !important;
border-left: 2px solid rgb(75, 202, 129) !important;
}
```

And it will change the color of the tick mark
[image]

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: The above works, I would just like to know if there is any selector attribute which can change the tick mark colour as well?

Comment: Yes sure, I have edited the answer and added the step to change the color of the tick mark as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try some workaround like inspecting the CSS of input element and apply the color like below:

```
Component:
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global">
<aura:attribute name="color" type="string" default=""/>
<aura:attribute name="isPVisible" type="boolean" default="true"/>
<lightning:input type="checkbox" label="P" 
                                onchange="{!c.change}"/> 
<aura:html  tag="style">
  .slds-form-element .slds-checkbox [type=checkbox]+.slds-checkbox_faux, .slds-form-element .slds-checkbox [type=checkbox]+.slds-checkbox--faux, .slds-form-element .slds-checkbox [type=checkbox]~.slds-checkbox_faux, .slds-form-element .slds-checkbox [type=checkbox]~.slds-checkbox--faux, .slds-form-element .slds-checkbox [type=checkbox]+.slds-checkbox__label .slds-checkbox_faux, .slds-form-element .slds-checkbox [type=checkbox]+.slds-checkbox__label .slds-checkbox--faux {
   background-color: {!v.color};
 }
</aura:html>
</aura:component>

   Controller:
change: function(component, event, helper) {
 if(component.get("v.color")){
      var clrValue='red';
      component.set('v.color',clrValue);
      console.log('color---'+component.get("v.color"));
 }
```

}